# Excel sheet is not opening in server side but it is opening in local

Tags: java, excel

[image]    String filepath="";

```
try {
    //String filename=file_name.replace('/','_');
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(file_name);
    HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
    filepath=prop.getProperty("file_store_path")+file_name+timeStamp+".xls";

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
    /*   rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Domain ID");*/
    rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Person ID");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Domain ID");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("First Name");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("Last Name");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("Email Address");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue("SBU");

    int i = 1;

    while (rs.next()){
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);

        /* row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString("domain_id"));*/
        row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString("person_id"));
        row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString("domain_id"));
        row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString("first_name") );
        row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getString("last_name"));
        row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getString("email_address"));
        row.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(rs.getString("business_unit"));

        i++;
    }

    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    System.out.println("XLS done!!"); 
}
```

I am having some issue with excel sheet exporting in Server side. The sheet is working fine in local but not working when deploying in Server. I am using XSSF format here (I have also used HSSF but getting different issue with that). I have attached the error message here.

How can I solve this issue?

The error I am getting is

```
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at com.controllers.ActiveUserReport.getDownloaded(ActiveUserReport.java:308)
        at com.controllers.ActiveUserReport.doGet(ActiveUserReport.java:113)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
```

Comment: where is erro message @Priyu

Comment: Can You send the error logs??

Comment: But you don't open an `Excel`, you build one. You are opening a `FileOutputStream` to push the value into the `Workbook` ( never try that from an `xls`). Show the stacktrace to see what part is not working.

Comment: What is the property file_store_path in the remote site?